# l1maggic compressive sensing Problems on Matlab

Tags: matlab-guide

1. I have downloaded the `l1magic` online (compressive sensing)
2. I'm trying to run a corrected perturbed array antenna using the codes below.

I'm getting these errors:

> "Error using  *  Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check
>   that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of
>   rows in the second matrix. To perform element wise multiplication, use
>   '.*'.
>
> Error in l1eq_pd (line 74)   if (norm(A*x0-b)/norm(b) > cgtol)
>
> Error in lineararrayl1 (line 86) xp = l1eq_pd(x0, A, [], y);
>   % xp = l1eq_pd(x0, A, [], y);

Comment: N = 10;                             
Nsubarray = 5;                      
ula = phased.ULA(N);                

rs = rng(7);           
pertStDev = 0.1;        

perturbedULA = clone(ula);
perturbedULA.Taper = 1+randn(1,N)*pertStDev;
c = 3e8;                              
freq = 2.45e9;                       
figure (1);
subplot(2,1,1);
helperCompareResponses(perturbedULA,ula,'Amplitude Perturbation', ...
                       {'Perturbed','Ideal'});

subplot(2,1,2);
stem(perturbedULA.Taper)
title('Amplitude Tapers');xlabel('Sensor');ylabel('Gain');
grid on;
hold on;

Comment: %% L1 compressive sensing
rng(0);                
N = 10;                 
P = 0;                  
x = ones(N,1);          % original signal 

peaks = randperm(N);
peaks = peaks(1:P);
x(peaks) = randn(1,P);         %x(peaks) = randn(1, P);
amp = 1.2*max(abs(x));
figure (2); 
subplot(3,1,1); 
plot(x); 
title('Uniform Linear Array Original signal');xlabel('Elements');ylabel('Amplitude');
grid on;
hold on;

Comment: % Clone the ideal ULA
perturbedULA = clone(ula);
perturbedULA.Taper = 1+randn(1,N)*pertStDev;    % perturbedULA.Taper = 1+randn(1,K)*pertStDev;
K = perturbedULA.Taper;                         % K = perturbedULA.Taper;
Ax = K;                                          %A = randn(K, N); % A = randn(K, N);        %A = randn(K, N);
A = Ax';                                        % A = Ax';

y = A.*x;                                        

subplot(3,1,2); 
plot(y);
title('Uniform Linear Array Perturbed signal');xlabel('Elements');ylabel('Amplitude');
grid on;
hold on;

Comment: x0 = A.*y;                                 % x0 = A.*y';    x0 = A.*y';  x0 = A'.*y'; 
xp = l1eq_pd(x0, A, [], y);                 % xp = l1eq_pd(x0, A, [], y);

subplot(3,1,3);
plot(real(xp));
title('Uniform Linear Array Recovered signal');xlabel('Elements');ylabel('Amplitude');
grid on;
hold on;